# If $n$ odd, does $\begin{pmatrix}\zeta&0\\ 0&\zeta^{-1}\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$ generate the dihedral group?

Tags: group-theory

For personal interest, I'm working on an solution of Serge Lang's Algebra.

Then I came across a problem about a group made up of two matrices like below.
$$\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\zeta&0\\ 0&\zeta^{-1}\end{pmatrix}, \tau=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Of course, $\zeta$ is primitive $n$-th root of unity, and $n$ is odd positive integer.

I don't think this group can actually be a dihedral group of order $4n$, because $\tau^2=I$ does not hold. But Lang denoted this group as $D_{4n}$, which is dihedral group of order $4n$.

I would like to ask if this group is a dihedral in some way that I am not aware of. I believe it is a dicyclic group of order $4n$.

Original image is below. There are no order 2 element I think.
[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks @DietrichBurde. I add original image in my book.

Comment: The given elements satisfy $\sigma^\tau = \sigma^{-1} \ne \sigma$ (for $n > 1$). In a dihedral group, any two elements of order $>2$ commute. So, correct, the group is not dihedral. Perhaps Lang just made a misleading choice of notation.

Comment: @Anne Bauval oh, the 2 matrices in part b are not $\tau$ and $\sigma$ in part a, and $D_{4n}$ are the matrix generated by them only

Comment: @AnneBauval I know what you mean and I only think the question by Lang create some misleading impressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although he denoted it by $D_{4n},$ Lang never claimed this group was the dihedral group of order $4n.$ Actually, it cannot, since $\tau$ is of order $4,$ whereas the exponent of the dihedral group of order $4n$ is $2n,$ and $n$ is assumed to be odd.

Denoting by $\sigma,\tau$ (like you did) Lang's two matrices and letting
$$a=\sigma\tau^2\quad\text{and}\quad x=\tau,$$ we recognize his "$D_{4n}$" as the [dicyclic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicyclic_group)
$$Q_{4n}=\operatorname{Dic}_n = \left\langle a, x \mid a^{2n} = 1,\ x^2 = a^n,\ x^{-1}ax = a^{-1}\right\rangle.$$